# TexMaker does not compile, redirects to /run/user/1000 instead

Tags: miktex, texmaker, linux

I've recently migrated to linux mint, being a former windows user.
I suspect the problem is somewhat linux related, but I could be totally wrong.

I am using TexMaker with MikTex. My problem is that when I use TexMaker to compile documents which are located someplace within `~/Documents/random_dir` everything works fine.
However, if I try to compile the same files located someplace else on my harddrive, say `~/Dropbox/random_dir` or `~/projects/random_dir`, I can open the .tex files but I get obscure error messages, like "log file not found" or that the style class is not found, although it is located within the same directory, AND it has been working flawlessly in the previous location.

I noticed that when opening the file, the file location as stated by TexMaker also does not correspond to the actual file location, but to some subdirectory within `/run/user/1000/doc`?! Under these conditions it of course makes sense, that dependencies are not to be found, but I have no idea how to solve the issue, despite searching for quite a while now.

Apparently opening the local .tex files somehow redirects me to a copy of the file located in `/run/user/1000`, but I have no idea under what conditions this is happening. Permission wise, all directories I tried where identical, providing read and write access to user.

Any ideas how to solve this issue??

Thanks in advance,
David

Comment: What happens if you cd into the troublesome directories and compile your documents from the command line?

Comment: Doing `lualatex filename.tex` does lead to the document compiling. However, it seems all packages are downloaded again (although I did use lualatex to complile from TexMaker before), there are a hole bunch of errors regarding fonts not found etc, and the final document is full of errors. However, it seems to be compiling from the correct file path, since all the local dependencies are found.

Comment: It's always hard to fix these problems remotely ... try doing `sudo texhash` in the terminal and then compiling from the command line again. Does it look any better?

Comment: No, does not look any better. However, the looks after compiling from command line are not my (main) issue. I am able to produce a good looking document, without any errors whatsoever. But only from TexMaker (which I am fine with) and only from certain directories, e.g. ~/Documents. I have not yet discovered a rule regarding what directories it works from, and from which is does not. All I know is that sometimes, instead of opening the right document, TexMaker opens  a copy of the document located in /run/user/1000, instead, which then, of course, does not compile.

Comment: The first thing to determine is where the problem lies. Sometimes there is a problem with the TeX installation, but sometimes it is caused by the editor. By working from the command line, we can rule out the second possibility for now. So, let's confirm: does command line compiling work without issues in the directories where TeXMaker fails?

Comment: Another test: open a .log file created after running lualatex from the command line, and open another .log file created after running from TeXMaker. Compare the version numbers in the same line. Are they the same? I ask because I think you may have two separate TeX installations.

Comment: Compiling from command line works in the faulty directories, for both pdftex and lualatex. If I try to create a new document from within TexMaker and save to one of the faulty directories, it instead saves and opens the document to /run/user/1000. I think that look like its a MikTex problem?

Comment: Regarding your second comment: If I switch to a non-faulty directory, and inspecting the .log files, using TexMaker I get `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)  (format=lualatex 2020.9.13)  11 DEC 2020 12:39`, if compiling from command line I get `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 20.11) (format=lualatex 2020.12.10)  11 DEC 2020 12:37`.